# GitKraken won't open on Windows 10

Tags: git, gitkraken

For some reason my gitkraken won't open. (windows 10 machine) This is the error I have in the debug.log file in my Local/gitkraken/app-9.1.0 folder:

```
[0209/091426.280:FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(495)] Error loading V8 startup snapshot file
```

I tried deleting the .gitkraken folder in %appdata%, still wont open.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error on Windows 11:

**FATAL:v8_initializer.cc(528)] Error loading V8 startup snapshot file**

This solution that worked for me:

1. Navigate to %APPDATA%\Local\gitkraken\app-<**previous-version**> (in my case, %APPDATA%\Local\gitkraken\app-9.1.1).
2. Run gitkraken.exe from there.

Result:

The app was able to launch.

The previous version has a local v8_context_snapshot.bin, so I assume it was able to launch with that and that file from the latest version was corrupted.

Since the relaunch, I haven't had the issue repeat.

This may not work for everyone, but it saves deleting the profile data in %APPDATA%\Roaming.gitkraken as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Thanks!  Launching from an older version worked for me but still prevented me from opening using the main path.  After running from the previous updated path I waited for it to prompt to update.  After updating and restarting it worked fine